# In modeling context: How to call a method that placed outside class

Tags: model, uml, software-design, staruml, argouml

[image]

For example if method A return either 0 or 1 .

If method A returns 1 then it should call method B.

How to visualize this in Class Diagram ?

Answer (score 2):

class diagrams are static diagrams, you can not show the behavior in a class diagram. You have to do a sequence or activity diagram.

see [sparx tutorial](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/fragment.html) or [eclipse tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9DUHOr_ANA)
For your case, an opt combined fragment should do the job.